# how to display the database records with MySQL Query

Tags: mysql, database

I have a table like this :

```
---------------------
| id | code | total |
---------------------
| 1  | AA01 |   5   |
| 2  | AA01 |   10  |
| 3  | AA01 |   7   |
| 4  | AA02 |   3   |
| 5  | AA02 |   1   |
---------------------
```

how to create a MySQL query if it looks like this :

```
--------
| code |
--------
| AA01 |
| AA02 |
--------
```

I tried the following query :

```
SELECT * FROM `buckets` WHERE `code` = 'FFF071214095758' or `code` = 'FFF071214101258'
```

but that is displayed is the whole record. I need only
display each code with only one record with the same code.
MySql query can do that?

Comment: I dont understand how your query relates to the sample data.

Comment: You can see that this is nonsensical, right?

Comment: This doesn't make any sense after the last edit you did. Is the column that holds the value `FFF071214095758` really `code`? If so your question does not make sense in relation to the sample data. Is there another table or column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably either want:

```
SELECT code 
FROM `buckets` 
WHERE `code` = 'AA01' 
   OR `code` = 'AA02' 
GROUP BY code
```

or:

```
SELECT DISTINCT code 
FROM `buckets` 
WHERE `code` = 'AA01' 
   OR `code` = 'AA02'
```

Comment: @Bonatoc No, I don't think `limit`would be helpful here, and certainly not without an `order by`clause.

Comment: — right. Still, the OP does not make clear if he needs some kind of sorting.

Answer (score 0):

You can try...

```
SELECT DISTINCT code 
FROM `buckets` 
WHERE `kode_transaksi` = 'FFF071214095758' or `kode_transaksi` = 'FFF071214101258'
```